# Instance Variable Not Retaining Value

Tags: ios5, clgeocoder

I'm trying to forward geocode an address in iOS 5 using the CLGeocoder object and the put the resulting CLLocation in an instance variable.  For some reason, I can set the instance variable and then call its getter, but the variable loses its value outside the scope of the Geocoder's completion handler.

I declared the variable in my .h file:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocation *specifiedPosition;
```

Then synthesized it in my .m:

```
@synthesize specifiedPosition = _specifiedPosition;
```

And then tried to use the geocoder like this - the first NSLog returns a latitude and longitude, while the second does not:

```
-(void)getLatLong:(NSString *)locationText
{

if (!self.geocoder)
{
    self.geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
}

[self.geocoder geocodeAddressString:locationText completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error){

    if ( ([placemarks count] > 0) && (error == nil)) {

        self.specifiedPosition = [[placemarks objectAtIndex:0] location];
        NSLog(@"Specified Location variable is set to: %@", self.specifiedPosition);


    } else if (error == nil && [placemarks count] == 0){
        // TODO
        NSLog(@"Can't find data on the specificed location");
    }
    else if (error != nil){
        // TODO
        NSLog(@"An error occurred = %@", error);
    }

}];

NSLog(@"Specified Location variable is set to: %@", self.specifiedPosition);

}
```

I also tried a custom setter, but that didn't help:

```
-(void)setSpecifiedPosition:(CLLocation *)specifiedPosition
{
    _specifiedPosition = specifiedPosition;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with this particular API, but the fact that it's taking a block called `completionHandler` very strongly suggests that this is an *asynchronous* operation. That is, your block will be invoked *later* (from the run loop). Your second `NSLog` in the source code is happening *before* the `completionHandler` is invoked, so it of course does not see the assignment since it hasn't happened yet.

Whatever you need to do once you have the specifiedPosition data, you should do it either inside of the `completionHandler` block, inside of `-setSpecifiedPosition:`, or somewhere else that is notified/triggered/called by one of those.

Comment: I think that's right - taking a look at the timestamps reveals that they are out of order.  Thank you!!!

Comment: @AlexSBerman Glad I could help. If it turns out to solve your problem, please click the checkmark to accept this answer.